# my question is about stuffed pork loin cooking time

Tags: cooking-time

I have a 2.25 lb stuffed pork loin with prosciutto and spinach. How long do I cook and at what temp?

Answer (score 1):

Time is going to vary on your oven, the moisture in your meat and stuffing.

Pork loin is good at 140F I wouldn't cook it any more than that.